# Get And Display List Of Installed Programs on Android

Tags: java, android, list, menu, android-alertdialog

I'm currently developing an app that will allow the user to choose an app and launch it at a later time (there is more functionality but this is the main thing I'm having an issue with.)

I'm looking for a way to get a list of the applications (user installed or updateable ex. Gmail, GMaps, etc...) And throw it into an AlertDialog similar to how you add a shortcut to the Homescreen (Long press -> Applications).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165023/get-list-of-installed-android-applications) is the thread I'm using that has the code to get the list of applications that I need. However how would I turn this into an AlertDialog?

Here is the code from the thread.

```
public void getApps()
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

    for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
        //checks for flags; if flagged, check if updated system app
        if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1) {
            installedApps.add(app);
        //it's a system app, not interested
        } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            //Discard this one
        //in this case, it should be a user-installed app
        } else {
            installedApps.add(app);
        }
    }
}//end getApps()
```

And here is the code I use for displaying an AlertDialog similar to what I want to use.

```
//PseudoCode does not compile
public void displayAppList(View v)
{
    final CharSequence[] items = {getApps()};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SchedulerActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose an App To Launch");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            appChoiceString[count] = items[item];
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       Toast.makeText(SchedulerActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
     });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       Toast.makeText(SchedulerActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
     });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Any help as to getting this to display properly would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the standard intent chooser? (See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)). Otherwise, you probably want to explain what is not displaying the way you want, and how you really want it to look in detail.

Comment: I have nothing to display at the moment. I have a List(see above) of all the user installed/updateable apps and I want to figure out a way to put that into an AlertDialog(List with Radio Buttons and an Ok/Cancel button). I've never used Intent and every time I've tried to read the articles it just seems like jibberish to me with no actual example code.

Comment: In order to launch apps, etc. you're going to have to understand intents at some point. It's a fundamental part of how Android apps work. You've probably already seen this, but this doc is probably a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: I actually hadn't seen that before. Thanks for the link.