# WSO2 EMM - Application list

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

The application list on device management tab didn't show all app installed on device.
[Here](http://tinypic.com/r/2druhs4/8) is the app on home page of my device (others all also installed) and [here](http://tinypic.com/r/15qrm0h/8) is the list of app recognized by emm

how can I fix this issuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it does not show system apps. In your case, the apps you don't see are system apps. We track the apps which are installed by the user and the enterprises. We have filtered the apps functionality to show only user-installed apps.

Thanks

Comment: How can I change it to show all app installed on device?

Comment: Hi Zahra,

Error shows that there's a connection timeout. Gmail SMTP might be blocking your authentication request. Usually it throttles 3rd party client requests unless you disable security from your mail account settings. 

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell which class I should change?

Comment: It's in the api package. Class name is ApplicationManager.java

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165023/get-list-of-installed-android-applications) is the link to get all app installed on android device.

Comment: Yes. We have the same mechanism in our ApplicationManager API. We have introduced a flag there, if you make it true, you will get system apps.

Answer (score 1):

I changed 3 variables for it to show the system apps. It's possible not all 3 are required, but it's how I got it to work (for ***WSO2 EMM 2.1.0 alpha***).

I applied the following changes:

In **ApplicationManager.java**:

```
SYSTEM_APPS_DISABLED_FLAG = 1;
```

In **Constants.java**:

```
SYSTEM_APP_ENABLED = true;
ALLOW_SYSTEM_APPS_IN_APPS_LIST_RESPONSE = true;
```