# How to access the names of android apps?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to access the names of **android** apps whenever I open any of them, and send them to the cloud. Is it possible to retrieve the information about apps from the system?
If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by apps? Please make your question clear.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I tried something, but nothing worked... I deleted the code I have written before.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I mean the apps on your phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of installed android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165023/get-list-of-installed-android-applications)

Answer (score 1):

First check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) to better understand the ResolveInfo class.

Then try this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List appsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0);
```

You will get all the necessary data in the ResolveInfo.