# Find all installed apps

Tags: android

How can I get the lists of installed Apps in `Android` similar to what we can see in phone settings within installed Apps. Also I would like to know theirs location and if possible permissions. I'm using Java language with `Android Studio`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165023/get-list-of-installed-android-applications

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get a list of installed apps:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> infos = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

ApplicationInfo contains a lot of information about the app, like the name, the packagename, minSdkVersion, some paths and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet would help you.

```
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```